# JQUERY how to set data on html content?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable s that contains string

```
'<div>hello world</div>'
```

(I cannot change the content of s)

I would like to set data on s
I tried:

```
$(s).data('value', 50);
$($(s)).data('value', 50);
```

Any idea ?

```
s = '<div>hello world</div>';
s = $(s).data('value', 50); // works now !!!
console.log($(s).data('value'));
```

Comment: s is some AJAX result !

Comment: whole problem stems from making a new object each time from same original string. That string will not be modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example (`$(s).data('value', 50);`) is working fine. You won't see it update in the DOM as jQuery holds `data` attributes in an internal cache for better performance. You can verify it worked by reading the value back out:

```js
var $div = $('div');

console.log('before: ' + $div.data('value'));
$div.data('value', 50);
console.log('after: ' + $div.data('value'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello world</div>
```

If you would prefer to update the `data-value` attribute in the DOM, use `attr()`, like this:

```js
var $div = $('div');
$div.attr('data-value', 50);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>hello world</div>
```

Use the DOM inspector to see the effect of the above code.

Comment: My first example DOES NOY WORK fine: $(s).data('value') GIVES me UNDEFINED !

Comment: In that case please provide a full example of your code. The little you've given is next to useless. Also check the console for errors as there is no reason for the above not to work.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can make what you are showng work is to store a reference to the original object...then get the value from that object

```
var $s = $(s).data('value', 500);
console.log($s.data('value'));
```

What you are currently doing is creating two objects using the same original string and there is no reference between those objects

```
$(s) == $(s)// false
```